# Location of transformer

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, inductor

This is for a POE application. The inductor is in net with the capacitor, as the first attached image shows. I moved this [inductor](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/49bc46c8-4b2c-45b9-9b6c-2eaa235ea698/xal50xx.pdf) from the previous design bottom of board to its new location. Can being close to this [47uF/100V capacitor](https://jianghai-america.com/uploads/products/radial/CD284.pdf) cause any issues? There are two unshielded ferrites down center so I moved it high up away from its previous location. We will be seeing 33- 57V before the inductor.

We want to use this board with a flex pcb attached to the back so we would prefer minimal components on the bottom.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't know what the inductor and capacitor are doing or what the whole circuit is for. Please [edit] to give some context to the question.

Comment: Edited can you please take a look?

Comment: The proximity of the Cap and the inductor is mainly a question of assembly. As the Inductor is SMD and the capacitor THT there should be a "bigger" gap as if both parts were smd. However, this seems fine. As a tipp: I would use way more vias for the inductor connections. Maybe 3x3 or even 4x4. Doesnt add cost, reduces inductance and resistance. Also for the Leg of the capacitor going from top to bottom. Just add a few vias close by.

Comment: Thank you I will add more vias